# Vue js: Change value using if else

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and I have two button. One is to show the login section and one is to show the register section. What I am tryin to achieve is, if I click on the login button, I want the login section to show and if I click on the register button, I want to hide login section and the register section to show. And by default, I want the login section to be showing. And also, if I click on the login button or Join button and that section was already showing, I want to keep that section showing. Is there a way to achieve this using if else statement or is there a better way to do this. Below is my code

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    displayLoginPage: true,
    displayJoinPage: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid p-0" id="app">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 sub-title">
        <div class="col horizontal-line">
          <h5>PERSONAL DETAILS</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-color-per">
          <p>Make Sure All Enter Information Are Correct</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center entry-section col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-login" id="show-login-section">
        <button @click="displayLoginPage = !displayLoginPage"  type="button" name="btn button">
          Login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-join" id="show-join-section">
        <button @click="displayJoinPage = !displayJoinPage" type="button" name="btn button">
          Join</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-show="displayLoginPage">
    <h5>Hello Login Page</h5>
    </div>
    <div v-show="displayJoinPage">
    <h5>Hello Register Page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single boolean, since there are only two views. Set the variable to `true` to show the login view and hide the other, and vice versa for `false`. Additionally, replace `v-show` with [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) and [`v-else`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="displayLoginPage = true">Login</button>
    <button @click="displayLoginPage = false">Join</button>

    <div v-if="displayLoginPage">
      <h5>Hello Login Page</h5>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <h5>Hello Register Page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      displayLoginPage: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    displayLoginPage: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid p-0" id="app">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 sub-title">
      <div class="col horizontal-line">
        <h5>PERSONAL DETAILS</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-color-per">
        <p>Make Sure All Enter Information Are Correct</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center entry-section col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-login" id="show-login-section">
      <button @click="displayLoginPage = true" type="button" name="btn button">
          Login</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-join" id="show-join-section">
      <button @click="displayLoginPage = false" type="button" name="btn button">
          Join</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div v-if="displayLoginPage">
    <h5>Hello Login Page</h5>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <h5>Hello Register Page</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you plan to have more than two views, you could set the variable to a string specific to each view. For example, set `displayPage` to `"login"` to show the login-view; or `"join"` to show the join-view. Change your `v-show` condition to compare `displayPage` against the corresponding value:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="displayPage = 'login'">Login</button>
    <button @click="displayPage = 'join'">Join</button>

    <div v-show="displayPage == 'login'">
      <h5>Hello Login Page</h5>
    </div>
    <div v-show="displayPage == 'join'">
      <h5>Hello Register Page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      displayPage: 'login'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    displayPage: 'login'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid p-0" id="app">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 sub-title">
      <div class="col horizontal-line">
        <h5>PERSONAL DETAILS</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-color-per">
        <p>Make Sure All Enter Information Are Correct</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center entry-section col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-login" id="show-login-section">
      <button @click="displayPage = 'login'" type="button" name="btn button">
          Login</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-join" id="show-join-section">
      <button @click="displayPage = 'join'" type="button" name="btn button">
          Join</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-show="displayPage == 'login'">
    <h5>Hello Login Page</h5>
  </div>
  <div v-show="displayPage == 'join'">
    <h5>Hello Register Page</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to explicitly set the values for `displayLoginPage` and `displayJoinPage` when either button is clicked. See the following example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    displayLoginPage: true,
    displayJoinPage: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid p-0" id="app">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 sub-title">
        <div class="col horizontal-line">
          <h5>PERSONAL DETAILS</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-color-per">
          <p>Make Sure All Enter Information Are Correct</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center entry-section col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-login" id="show-login-section">
        <button @click="(displayLoginPage = true) && (displayJoinPage = false)"  type="button" name="btn button">
          Login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 entry-option-button-join" id="show-join-section">
        <button @click="(displayJoinPage = true) && (displayLoginPage = false)" type="button" name="btn button">
          Join</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-show="displayLoginPage">
    <h5>Hello Login Page</h5>
    </div>
    <div v-show="displayJoinPage">
    <h5>Hello Register Page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```